Client Side Validation on CKEditor
I have a CKEditor for editing a news content field.
I have done client-side validation for the create page and it works but when on the edit page if I remove the already existing content and submit I get the validation message but the submit button is disabled and when I start typing on the editor the red-colored validation message is not showing.
[This is where I am loading the CKEditor and the existing content]
<div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('contents') ? 'has-error' : 'has-success' }}">
                                                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Content
                                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                                            <textarea name="contents" id="editor" class="form-control" rows="10">{!! $news->contents !!}</textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

(https://i.sstatic.net/f5qJdvD6.png)
This is the validation part
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#editForm').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap4',
            excluded: ':disabled',
            live: 'disabled',
            fields: {
                
                contents: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The contents is required'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            var $form = $(e.target),
            $button = $form.data('formValidation').getSubmitButton();
            $('input[name=button_type]').val($button.attr('id'));
        }); 
        $("input").change(function(){
            $('#editForm').formValidation('revalidateField', $(this).attr('name'));
        });

        $("#btn_curr_image").click(function(){
            $('#img_curr_image').removeAttr('src')
            $('#img_curr_image').show();
            $('#curr_image_url').val("");
        });
    });


    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
        .then(editor => {
            
            editor.setData(document.getElementById('editor').value);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was an error initializing the editor', error);
    });

